# Can a magnet or a magnetic field push gravity?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity

I have been asking around at my school and at the high school and at EWU but no one can answer this question: can a magnet or a magnetic field push gravity?

Comment: What does "push gravity" mean?

Comment: The magnetic field strengths typically encountered with things like refrigerator magnets and electromagnets don't really affect gravity all that much (if at all). Truly gigantic magnetic fields (like in magnetars) might (?) be another story, but I don't have any expertise on the matter.

Comment: "push gravity" is a rather vague description, could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: A magnetic field can induce a force opposing the gravitational force, if that's what you mean. Or if you're talking about the much more advanced topic of coupling between gravity and electromagnetism, probably in the context of general relativity (as the retagging by @Draksis would suggest), you'll want to start by reading e.g. [this wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime).